# Codeigniter Severity warning

Tags: php, codeigniter

### Problem

I am trying to use file_get_contents However that gives me error

> A PHP Error was encountered

I tried to change in `php.ini` `allow_url_fopen = 1` however no result.

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: file_get_contents(https://api.telegram.org/bot [number token]/getUpdates):

Filename: controllers/lifeChange.php


Line Number: 19

Backtrace:

File: C:\OpenServer\domains\localhost\admin\application\controllers\lifeChange.php
Line: 19
Function: file_get_contents

File: C:\OpenServer\domains\localhost\admin\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once
```

Comment: Please post your code for `lifeChange.php`, and also check your server logs for more detailed error messages.

Comment: First off your controller is named wrong for Codeigniter should be `controllers/Lifechange.php` and `class Lifechange extends CI_Controller {}` The **first letter only** of filename and class to be upper case

Comment: I tested how you said no result

Comment: Put url into quotes.

Comment: yes I already putted, I think problem with local server